# How do I make a div covering an iframe fade on hover making the iframe clickable?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an overlay on top of a full-frame google docs iframe. I want the top section of the docs to be covered by an 100% width div which fades on hover, revealing the docs options which become clickable.

I've got the fade transition working but the invisible div blocks the iframe from been clicked. If I use pointer-events:none, change the z-index or display:none I get a nasty flickering effect when the cursor is moved.

Is there a work around?

https://github.com/plasticplant/miscresearch/tree/master/miscresearch

```
#background-site {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#background-site iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: 'Sporting_Grotesque-Bold';
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: white;
 }

  #header:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```
<div id="header">
miscresearch
</div>

<div id="background-site"><iframe name="backgrnd" id="backgrnd" scrolling="yes" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/16_jikyP9LfNibSOvM4XPeuB2jhf8YEYES1p8xhTBBDM/edit?usp=sharing"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: share your code, so we can answer!

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan, I've added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using z-index is a better approach because when you do `display:none;` on :hover you are not hovering any element so the nasty effect happens.

```
#header:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this. Unfortunately it still produces the flickering effect.

Comment: I did yeah, but it is still too glitchy / flickery when the cursor moves for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work -- i replicated your problem using some divs, but it gets the point across.

First, use the style "pointer-event:none;" to make the upper level div able to be selected through. The lower div has mouseover and mouseout events that call javascript to change the opacity of the overlay.

You can try applying the mouseover and mouseout functions to the div containing the iframe

```js
function hidefunc(){
  document.getElementById("test").style.opacity = '0';
}
function showfunc(){
  document.getElementById("test").style.opacity ="1"
}
```

```css
#test{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:#000000;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  pointer-events:none;
  z-index:2;
}
#base{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:0;
  height:50px;
  width:600px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
<div onmouseover="hidefunc()" onmouseout="showfunc()" id="base">
  <a href="">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your thinking but sadly the red base div isn't detected underneath the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Iframes have a load event, which fire once they have loaded.
Simply create your overlay, and remove it once the iframe's onload event fires.

HTML:

```
<div id="background-site" class="showOverlay">
    <iframe name="backgrnd" id="backgrnd" scrolling="yes" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/16_jikyP9LfNibSOvM4XPeuB2jhf8YEYES1p8xhTBBDM/edit?usp=sharing"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background-site {
    position: relative;
}

#background-site.showOverlay:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

JS :

```
document.getElementById("backgrnd").addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("background-site").classList.remove('showOverlay')
});
```

Fr the current code you could also use the parentElement, to achieve the same result, as the event fires on the iframe:

```
document.getElementById("backgrnd").addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.remove('showOverlay')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've a working solution (see below).

Unfortunately it requires (vanilla) JavaScript; I hope you don't mind. I tried several CSS solutions like animations and all but to no avail.

Anyways, the trick is to use separate mouse in and mouse out event listeners on the iframe and overlays respectively.

```js
document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener("mouseover", overlayDisappear);
document.getElementById("theiframe").addEventListener("mouseout", overlayAppear);

function replaceAll(str, toFind, toReplace){
  return str.replace(new RegExp(toFind.toString(),"g"), toReplace.toString());
}

function overlayAppear(){
  //console.log("Appear", document.getElementById("overlay").className);
  document.getElementById("overlay").className = replaceAll( document.getElementById("overlay").className, "_disappear","_appear");  
}

function overlayDisappear(){
  //console.log("Disappear", document.getElementById("overlay").className);
  document.getElementById("overlay").className = replaceAll( document.getElementById("overlay").className, "_appear","_disappear");  
}
```

```css
#theiframe, #overlay{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

#theiframe{
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#overlay{
  background:red;
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
}

#overlay._appear{
  opacity:1;
  z-index:1;
}

#overlay._disappear{
  opacity:0;
  z-index:-1;
}

/*
#overlay:hover{
  animation-name: disappear;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes disappear{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0.5; }
  99%  { opacity:0; z-index:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}*/
```

```html
<iframe id="theiframe" src="https://samleo8.github.io/web"></iframe>
<div id="overlay" class="_appear"></div>
```

Comment: This works initially but because the iframe covers the entire page the div will not reappear.

Comment: Otherwise the mouse out event will never fire if it's the whole page